# PHP nested if conditions

Tags: php

What I'm trying to achieve is a nested condition like `if ((a = true && b = true) or (c = true && d = true)) {...}`.  This doesn't seem to be working for me.

To further explain: I have two variables in what we could call a 'top', and two variables in what we could call a 'bottom'.  What I need to do is execute code if variables are true in both 'top' and 'bottom'.

To more succinctly illustrate:

```
if ((t1 = true && b1 = true) or
    (t1 = true && b2 = true) or
    (t2 = true && b1 = true) or
    (t2 = true && b2 = true)
) {
    ...do some stuff...
}
```

I'm tempted to call it 'conditional statement for lattice problem'... except it isn't really a lattice problem... but it does sort of look like a lattice if you drew it `|X|` ... s'yeah, you're amazing if you can tell me a good way to do this, and you're super amazing if you can tell me what I ought to call it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`=` is used for assignment, `==` is used to test for equality, `===` is used to test for equality and equal types. You need to use either `==` or `===`, depending on whether t1, t2, b1, b2 are already boolean or something else. Also the stuff that Adam said, except that `or` is perfectly valid.

Comment: Well I feel a bit silly; tried checking them as `!= false` earlier but didn't take it all the way through the function.  Thank you much for the clearing up, Dan.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use two equal signs `==` instead of `=`.  Also, your variables need to have `$` in front of them.  And your "or" should be `||`.

The logic is ok.

It should look like this:

```
if (($t1 == true && $b1 == true) ||
    ($t1 == true && $b2 == true) ||
    ($t2 == true && $b1 == true) ||
    ($t2 == true && $b2 == true)
) {
    ...do some stuff...
}
```

Comment: Technically, he can use `or`, but I agree, it would be ridiculous to do so.

Comment: I did not know that.  Learn something new everyday :).  http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Comment: It's pretty inconsistent with PHP's C-like syntax.

Answer (score 0):

change condition

```
if (($t1 == true && $b1 == true) or
($t1 == true && $b2 == true) or
($t2 == true && $b1 == true) or
($t2 == true && $b2 == true)
)
```

`=` is assignment operator `==` is comparison operator.